# TreeMultimap not throwing out NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, guava, multimap

The below test example code is expected to throw a NullPointerException in runtime and print some stacktrace in the console. But it does not do so. Line 2 gets printed as if no error happened.

If you debug the execution, you see the expected exception 
"map.put( k: 3L, new House()); map: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap.toString()". But it does not break the execution as it should in case of a runtime exception.

Even if you try to catch the NullPointerException on the Line 1, it is not captured.

Why is it so?

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;   
import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap;
// from com.google.guava version 18.0

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Multimap<Long, House> map = TreeMultimap.create();
    map.put(3L, new House());  //**Line 1** . expected to break the execution.
    System.out.println("done"); // **Line 2**. expected to not get printed.

}

private static class House implements Comparable{

    Integer numberOfRooms_ = null;

    @Override

    public int hashCode() {

        return numberOfRooms_.hashCode(); //NullPointerException generated

    }

    @Override

    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        return 1;

    }

}
```

jdk 1.7 is used.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you shouldn't link the exception through an image, but directly in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Javadoc, `TreeMultimap` is](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) an:

> Implementation of `Multimap` whose keys and values are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators. **In all cases, this implementation uses `Comparable.compareTo(T)` or `Comparator.compare(T, T)` instead of `Object.equals(java.lang.Object)` *(or `hashCode` - Xaerxess)* to determine equivalence of instances**.

`hashCode` isn't called, but `compareTo` is, no NPE is thrown there. On the other hand, if you used `HashMultimap`, it'd fail to put object with `hashCode` implementation throwing NPE, because it uses `equals`/`hashCode` under the hood.

Comment: Thank you Xaerxess for your prompt reply. I checked using HashMultimap and got the expected exception.

Comment: Any reason why during debug, the hashCode( ) gets called? Only toString( ) should be called, isn't it?

Comment: Got it. toString( ) will call hashCode( ) cause I've not overriden it.

Comment: @RishirajDas You may want to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then.